# IntelliJ Jersey Web Service Deployment (Some tips and Template Project)

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea, jersey

How to set up Jersey 2.0 Web Services on IntelliJ IDE using Tomcat 7, with complete Maven support?

I have had quite a bit of trouble to put everything together to make it work. To hopefully save some time to people in the same situation, I have made a small guide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have taken the time to set up an IntelliJ 13.0 project for a web service using Jersey 2.0 and Tomcat 7, complete with Maven support.

Finally I managed to figure out the complete configuration and it works, so I have decided to give back to the stackoverflow community.

Here is a working [template project on GitHub](https://github.com/silvae86/IntelliJ13.0-JerseyWS) (you should only need to clone it and change the path of your Tomcat 7 installation).

Here are the relevant configuration screens that you can use to set up your Tomcat Home directory:

After cloning the project, go into run configurations.

[image: configurations]

Then change the tomcat home (here I used HomeBrew on the Mac)

[image: setting tomcat home]

I was getting a 404 error when accessing any of the WS's, I discovered I had to add all the Jersey and Glassfish JAR's to the lib directory under WEB-INF. Just create a lib folder and drag-and-drop all libs.

[image: drag-and-drop-libs]

Answer (score 1):

Fist of all, please make sure that you are using Ultimate Edition of IntelliJ Idea. Unfortunately, community edition does not support J2EE.
Second, here are the best instructions I found. It saved my day:

```
https://medium.com/@jamsesso/starting-out-with-jersey-apache-tomcat-using-intellij-6338d93ffd40
```